# Java import sentence

Tags: java, import

I wrote this command line:

```
Field [] field=Hello_World.class.getFields();
```

and I used the `import java.lang.*;` sentnce, that suppose to import all of the classes in the lang package. even so when i wrote this command line it throw me an errow and suggested to use the following import sentence: import java.lang.reflect.Field; which, to my understing, import the speciefic field class from the lang package. I dont understand why does my orginal import sentence doesn't solve this problem(It supposed to import all of the classes, doesn't it?)

Comment: As you can check in the possible dup question, `import` won't get the classes from the packages inside it recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You have two misconceptions:

- You don't need to import `java.lang`.  It is implicitly imported.
- Importing `xxx.*` imports only the classes and interfaces in `xxx`.  It does NOT import any "subpackages" of `xxx`; e.g. `xxx.yyy` or `xxx.yyy.zzz`.

So what you should do is get rid of `import java.lang.*`, and add `import java.lang.reflect.*`.

---

Aside: A lot of people (myself included) think that "star" importing classes and interfaces is a bad idea.  It can cause source-level fragility; e.g. if someone unexpectedly adds a class to some package that collides with a same-named class you've imported from another package.

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.* import all classes of lang packages but not its subpackages subclass. so to import the subclasses of reflect, you have to import java.lang.reflect.Field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how package imports work (and are supposed to work) in Java. For example, doing import javax.swing.*; will import all classes within javax.swing.* but not sub-packages and their classes.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is not in lang.* package. its subpackage to language package. You need import java.lang.reflect.* it ll work. As other answers imply that import doesn't import subpackages.